# How to test that parameter fields are being passed to the controller in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Basically, as my Rails 4.2 applications become more complicated, I sometimes forget to include the appropriate parameters in the user_params strong parameters hash.  This leads to information not being saved.  For example, I might forget to include the :nickname as per below code.

what's a good way to test that I have included the whitelisted parameters?  I don't care if they are nil or some other value, I just need a failing test to remind me to include the parameter.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:id, name, user_nested_attributes: [:nickname, :pet])
end
```

Comment: One option: You can use `assert_not_equal` on each attribute you want to see changed in your test. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#available-assertions

Comment: Another: The Shoulda Matchers gem has some explicit tests for params in your Controllers. http://matchers.shoulda.io/docs/v3.0.0/Shoulda/Matchers/ActionController.html#permit-instance_method

Comment: Do you mean that (for example) the `:nickname` param is missing from the request? or that `:nickname` should be whitelisted and it is not?

Comment: @zetetic, I meant that the :nickname parameter should be whitelisted, and I kept forgetting to include it in the controller.  lanny-bose, the shoulda matchers gem is perfect, thanks!